# Exclude displaying certain folders and subfolders in a Treeview

Tags: c#

on one of my drives I have a folder structure ex

d:\

```
123
    Code
        testfile.cs
    Database
        Backup.mdb
    Requirements
        Sprint1.xls

234
   20132305
        20132205
            20132105 
   Database
```

I would like to in my treeview show the following

d:\

```
123

    Code
        testfile.cs
    Database
        Backup.mdb 

234
   Database
```

i.e only show folders and subfolders for "code" and "database"

Here is the code to load the treeview

folderLst  = {"123","234"}

```
   private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        TreeNode rootNode;
        foreach (string f in folderLst)
        {

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\");
            if (info.Exists)
            {
                rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
                rootNode.Tag = info;
                GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
            }
        }
    }


  private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs, TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
    {
        TreeNode aNode;
        DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
        {
            aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
            aNode.Tag = subDir;

            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
            if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
            {
                GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
            }

            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
        }
    }
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, have you tried anything? How did that fail?

Comment: I have tried but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code

```
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
    {
        aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
        aNode.Tag = subDir;

        subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
        if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
        {
            GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
        }

        nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
    }
```

You can modify it to not add the desired folders

```
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
    {
        if(subDir.Name.Contains("Code") || subDir.Name.Contains("Database"))
        {
            aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
            aNode.Tag = subDir;

            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
            if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
            {
                GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
            }

            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eric I tried this approach but the tree view only shows "Code" and "Database" but does not show the subfolders